# Cant turn off Clojure parenthesis autocomplete in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, clojure, parentheses

Im working on a Clojure project using Eclipse, and for some reason it decided that all free will concerning parenthesis should be removed, and now when I type '(' it auto-completes it to '()'. The problem is that is I cannot just have one or the other; trying to delete the ')' character does nothing, and deleting the '(' character deletes both parenthesis. Modifying the Java => editor => typing tab under preferences does nothing,and the Clojure => editor tab has nothing useful. The only way i can successfully make a single '(' character is to copy it and at least another character [i.e. '(a'] and paste it, which is definitely not winning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated -- Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably paredit mode is on. Try Alt-d to turn it off or via the Clojure menu.

Answer (score 0):

It's a "feature" of the "unrestricted/default" editing mode in the current stable version of Counterclockwise.

It will be removed from the new version, because too many users have complained (and they were right) that it's not practical in "unrestricted/default" mode. (Of course it will still be available in paredit/strict mode, which is the mode I encourage you to use/learn if you do a lot of Clojure per day).

You can either switch back to the previous version of CCW, or wait for the next stable version (available in a week or two), or install the beta version in development (update site: http://ccw.cgrand.net/updatesite-betas/ )

Answer (score -1):

This is how paredit mode works.

It's actually *much more productive* once you get the hang of it: I therefore suggest *not* turning it off and learning how to make the most of it. You will be pleased that you did this, in the end.